# Default pressed MenuItem with 9-patch border after Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

After updating to Android Studio 2.2 and Android Plugin to 2.2.0-alpha1, I noticed that when I press a MenuItem, it gets a black border. I presume that this border is caused by a problem with its 9-patch pressed background. Is this a known issue?

[image]
This is the pressed state. The default state works fine.

Obs: I am testing on a real device and I had never experienced this issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change the default android plugin version 2.2 alpha to 2.1 stable.

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0`

Update : try latest version ( 2.2 ) when it become stable one

Comment: Yeah, this fix the issue but Android Studio 2.2 loses the ability to hotswap changes. I'll wait until 2.2 is stable. Thanks

Comment: @LuccasClezar Yea, Use the stable version now :)

Comment: thanks, didn't know it's a studio issue :( ... lost my day on this :'(